# Feedburner closing </head> error

Tags: tags, feedburner

This is the error I get from feedburner.

> "The URL does not appear to reference a valid XML file. We encountered
>   the following problem: Error on line 573: The element type "link" must
>   be terminated by the matching end-tag ""."

`http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cmchatlive.com%2F`

There is an opening `<head>`, tag but for some reason it is begin bypassed. Please advise.

Comment: Your feed works fine and valiates:
http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cmchatlive.com%2Ffeed%2F

Comment: thank you so much for the reply however when I try to add it to feedburner I keep getting the error: http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/addfeed

Comment: [Feedburner is dead](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=feedburner+is+dead) [(pretty much)](http://www.feedblitz.com/feedburner-shut-down-the-facts-and-tales-from-the-front-line/) - you'd be much better off using [another service](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=feedburner+alternative).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely that you have an improperly formatted post or headline in your XML feed that is breaking Feedburner. You should verify that your HTML tags are all properly closed in your first 10 posts.